# App Crashes When Trying to Sign In With an Unregistered Email

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

I have two gmail accounts on my phone. Only one of those accounts is registered to use the app. If I sign out of the app and try to sign in with Google using the unregistered email address, it first prompts which email I want to use, then me what permissions the app requests access to. I click OK and it looks like it is going to let me log in and then crashes (with the usual Android message "Unfortunately, Stack Exchange has stopped"). I'm not sure if this is because its still the alpha version, and I can't think of another app that has prompted me to choose between one of my gmail accounts so I'm not sure if other apps would do the same.

Obviously it shouldn't let me log in with the email that isn't registered. Instead of crashing though, I was expecting a message, something maybe along the lines of "This email address has not been registered with the Stack Exchange mobile app". (I'm sure that could be worded better) Didn't notice a post yet on this so figured I'd just point it out. This seems like a bug and a feature-request so I tagged it with both, but one or the other can be removed if its not technically both.

I'm on version 0.1.50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This will be fixed in version 0.1.51 coming out later tonight.

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark as answer after the update.